# UITabBarController item doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, xcode8, uitabbaritem

I am using `UITabBar Controller`

On pressing the second item it first go to First ViewController. I am not able to identify my mistake. Can someone help?

[image]

Comment: please add some code

Comment: https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/tab-bar-controller-tutorial-ios8-swift Check this tutorial

Comment: it should not go to the ViewController 
directly go to 1 - favouriteView

Comment: have you check identifier or connections  which you are using for second viewcontroller

Comment: Even pass a segue it First go to the ViewController then pass the Data